# The type to indicate keys that be set specific type value in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to make a type `KeyOfType<M, T>` for keys that be set specific type value.

```
interface MyTypeMap {
    "one": 1;
    "two": "hello";
    "three": 3;
    "four": "world";
    "five": 5;
};

type KeyOfType<M, T> = ....; // ?????

type Foo = KeyOfType<MyTypeMap, string>; // 'two' | 'four'
type Bar = KeyOfType<MyTypeMap, number>; // 'one' | 'three' | 'five'
```

I tried like below, but it's not working...

```
type KeyOfType<M extends {
  [key in keyof M]: any;
}, T> = M extends {
  [key in infer R]: T;
} ? R : never;
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) here, since remapping a key to `never` will remove it from the resulting type:

```
type KeyOfType<M, T> = keyof {
  [K in keyof M as M[K] extends T ? K : never]: K
};
```

This iterates over every key `K` in `M`, and checks of the value `M[K]` extends the `T` type. If it does, keep the key, else remap the key name to `never`, removing it. The value type doesn't matter since you only want the keys, so just shoving `K` in there seems fine. Then cram a `keyof` at the start to pull out just the keys.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2&ssl=11&ssc=3&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOFVw7IDeAUMhcgEQD2IEVAXMgIwDc5lVYA7jU9QAWEADYj+HStTCCoEBswDMkrjBoBXKAKp8oIgCZUVFKjGAA3BcgCsHAL4dSYXCgDSEdAHkY2PAB5UABpkTAA+ZABeZABrDxoYEk4AbVdkUBi4hNRkOABnNBSAXWQIAA9IEH18zGQAfmRU5npLKELmV1IHUicXZAAxGhpIho9vXwgArBcCHGDcsChQAHNQtmQAenXkAHJeGm3kAB8dtU1tnrxkACE4KGH3Lx8XSfGZ4JB1AFsAI2hVja22zoEAOx12snkoJOFhBQA)